# dynamic variable keeps recalculating (datetime for filename)

Tags: ssis

I have a problem in a small SSIS package that I'm trying to do for storing a query result into an excel file

I want the file to have a dynamic name of Missing_Timecards_#DATETIME#.xlsx

for example: "Missing_Timecards_20220808_131321.xlsx"

for this I have created a template file that has the columns and sheet name I want.

and I have set a system task to copy this template file into a new one with the dynamic name I want to have:

[image]

for the variables I have set a combination of a few fields to get my dynamic filename with the date:

[image]

the expression for getting the date is

```
REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)GETDATE(),1,19),"-",""),":","")," ","_")
```

so far so good, no errors here, when the process starts the variable gets calculated, the filetask creates a copy with the freshly calculated field and goes to the dataflow that retrieves the data and saves it into the excel file path set with the variable that was calculated originally for the filename+datetime

[image]

However here is where the issue appears, it seems that the variable is calculated again, so a new file gets created with a "fresh" datetime part of the name, and as the sheet name doesn't match it gives an error.

I think the issue is that is calculating the variable again, how do I stop this from happening?  (I have set delay validation = true in for the excel connection and the dataFlow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've identified, `GETDATE()` is calculated *each* time it is evaluated. Instead, I favor using a System scoped variable like `@[System::StartTime]` as it is the time the package started execution but remains constant for the duration of the package.

Literally, swap reference to getdate() with @[System::StartTime] and you're set.

The other option is to

1. Copy the existing expression to your clipboard
2. Clear the expression from the Variable
3. Add an `Expression Task` to the Control Flow and re-use the expression in the clipboard to assign the value to your `@[User::DateTime]` variable

Personally, I favor the former approach as a consultant because I still run into SQL Server 2008/R2 packages and the Expression Task was not available for the product.